# Cancel getJSON after pending request x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I am loading an ad network using this code:

```
$.getJSON('https://server.ads.io/api/v1/decision/?publisher=xx-com&ad_types=text-v1&format=jsonp', function (data) {
    $('#ea-wrapper').html(data.html);
});
```

In a scenario where `https://server.ads.io` takes too long to load, the browser will wait for the ad *ad aeternum*. What I am looking for, is a way to cancel the getJSON after, let's say, 3 seconds of waiting with no response. Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: you can use `$.ajax` and use `setTimeout` to `abort` the request after x second - Disclaimer: the request will only be cancelled be cancelled from the client side - server side might still be loading it in background - just for your information

Comment: @AlwaysHelping It's fine. My problem is only the client side. Can you please elaborate more about the solution?

Comment: Instead of getJSON, load it using ajax . Ajax has a timeout parameter

Comment: @anvd did my answer solved the question ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I will try more later. I will approve asap as it works

Comment: @anvd No problem. Let me know if i can need help further :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually [abort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) the request as mentioned in my comment.

You need to set the `getJSON` as `variable` and call that `variable` in a `setTimeout` after three seconds to `abort` the request.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //kill the request
   adRequest.abort()
}, 3000) //3 seconds
```

Final code you can try will be like this:

```
var adRequest = $.getJSON('https://server.ads.io/api/v1/decision/?publisher=xx-com&ad_types=text-v1&format=jsonp', function(data) {
  $('#ea-wrapper').html(data.html);
});

setTimeout(function() {
  //kill the request
  addRequest.abort()
}, 3000)  //3 seconds
```

If you want to use `$.ajax` you can use take advantage of native `timeout` method

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://server.ads.io/api/v1/decision/?publisher=xx-com&ad_types=text-v1&format=jsonp',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#ea-wrapper').html(data.html);
  },
  timeout: 3000 //3 seconds
});
```